# How to make two Div fixed with respect toeach other?

Tags: html, css

I have a Div below which is a button and as my screensize changes height of the Div changes due to which the button changes its position sometimes it hides behind the Div as I have provided z-index. How can I make position of the button fixed with respect to the Div even when the screensize changes?

Here is my HTML code:--

```
<div class="row" id="event">
          <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-xs-1"></div>
          <div class="col-lg-10  col-md-10  col-xs-10 ">
            <section *ngFor="let event of events; let i = index" [style.backgroundColor] = "colorsArray[i]" class="eventSectionCSS">
              <legend class="legendCSS"> {{event.title}}</legend>
<br>

                <div class="row" style="margin-left: 15px;" >
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6" style="display: inherit;" >

                  <div class="row" >
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                      <h2 class="presenterNameCSS" >{{ event.SMEPresentedByFirstName | uppercase}} </h2>
                    </div>

                     <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="margin-left: -10px;" >
                       <h2 class="presenterNameCSS" > {{ event.SMEPresentedByLastName | uppercase}} </h2>
                    </div>

                  </div>

                </div>
             <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" ></div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" id="image__event_both" >
                  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                                      <div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                    <div class="flipper">
                      <div class="front">
                          <img id="image__1" (click) = "clickToShare()" src="../assets/img/Fwd Icons/share.png" >
                      </div>
                      <div class="back">
                                    <div class="row" >
                              <section class="widget sharing_events_widget">
                                    <share-buttons  (click) = "closeShareIt(i)" [url]="'http://mentoriaweb.azurewebsites.net/#/app/Login'"
                                        [count]="false"
                                        [totalCount]="true"
                                        [defaultStyle]= "true"
                                        (popUpClosed) = "true"
                                        [google]="googleInner"
                                        [pinterest]="false"
                                        [linkedIn]="false"
                                        [tumblr]="tumblrInner"
                                        [reddit]="false"
                                        [stumbleUpOn]="false">
                                  </share-buttons>                
                              </section>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div> 
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                     <img id="image__2" (click) = "notifyMe(event.uid)" src="../assets/img/Fwd Icons/notify.png" > 
                  </div>                           
                </div>               
              </div>
<br>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 presenterImageDivCSS "  >
                  <img style="margin-left: 31px;" src="assets/img/avatar.png">
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                  <p class="smeSnippetCSS" > {{event.snippet}} </p>
                   <a style="color:#fff;" >...Read more</a>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 dashed_height"style="">
                  <div class="date1" >{{event.eventDate*1000 | date:'dd'}}</div>
                  <div class="date2"><b>{{event.eventDate*1000 | date:'MMM' | uppercase}}</b> <br>
                    <p class="date3">{{event.eventDate*1000 | date:'yyyy'}}</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="date4"> <b>{{ event.eventDate | date:'hh:mm a'}}</b></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <br>
            </section>
            <div>


             <button class="btn btn-primary width-100 mb-xs" id="sme_register" role="button" ><span class="sme_buttonn"><b> Register</b></span> </button>
            </div>


          </div>
          <div class="col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xs-1"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Working JSFiddle would be appreciated!

Comment: Here is section and below is the button as I canhge the screen size position of the button changes but I want it to be fixed. https://jsfiddle.net/1fjpenqg/

Comment: Above is my jsfiddle as you asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using position relative. Position fixed is respective to the screen.

The fiddle you updated is not showing what actually are upto. I can't see position fixed on button.

Comment: So you are saying I need to give the section position: relative and the button position: fixed.

Comment: No. Nothing should be fixed. I am decreasing the screensize of fiddle but button is not going behind the div.

Comment: Yes that is beacause I have provided z-index to the button and the section . Actually according to the requirement the button is supposed to be exactly below the section where the section will be covering a small portion of the button( thats why I provided z-index)

Comment: There is no zindex

Comment: Here I have removed the z-index. I hope this helps https://jsfiddle.net/uLsko80a/